# Linux Mint 16: Android Device not listed with lsusb

Tags: linux-mint, usb, usb-drive, android

I've installed Linux Mint 16 on my new PC and found out that my plugged in Huawei U8850 Android 2.3.5 device is not listed with the lsusb command:

phone plugged in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 057c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

using the -v option with the lsusb command i get one different line:

plugged in:

```
Port 7: 0000.0101 power connect
```

not plugged in:

```
Port 7: 0000.0100 power
```

I ensured that all is set up correctly:

1. device has usb debugging enabled
2. usb cable is ok
3. usb port on desktop PC is ok; a usb flash memory stick is recognized; the system was booted and installed via the same port.

The same hardware configuration was working ok 3 days ago, when I used the same PC with a now uninstalled elementary OS (based on ubuntu 12.04).

The phone and cable is today working on a Windows 8 system.

---

I am not absolutely sure about it, but I think successful listing with lsusb is the basis for the next step: set up a rules file.

Anyway, in case the above step is not essential, I've created such a file (steps below done as root):

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

with this content, using 12d1 as the vendor id (Huawei):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

(I am in the plugdev group)

Restart udev:

```
# restart udev
```

-> nothing changed. adb shows also nothing:

```
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

killing, restarting of adb changes nothing (tested as root and as a normal user):

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

- Rebooting the phone and PC doesn't change anything.
- Plug out / in doesn't change anything

These are the messages created in syslog, when the phone is plugged in:

```
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2638.923967] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2638.941035] usb 3-7: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2638.941141] usb 3-7: can't set HNP mode: -32
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.107756] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.124664] usb 3-7: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.124717] usb 3-7: can't set HNP mode: -32
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.291545] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.308422] usb 3-7: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.308473] usb 3-7: can't set HNP mode: -32
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.475327] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.492305] usb 3-7: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.492373] usb 3-7: can't set HNP mode: -32
Mar 11 13:07:01 rupert kernel: [ 2639.492419] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
```

---

**EDIT**
Just tested a bit. I've created 2 USB boot sticks, one with ubuntu 13, the other one with elementary OS.

I did not change or add anything, just booted from usb, opened a terminal and  entered the lsusb command.

Ubuntu 13: same as Mint 16; lsusb returns nothing, syslog looks similar.

Elementary Luna: lsusb shows the Huawei, with Vendor ID 12d1.
When plugging in the phone, numerous errors appears in syslog. However, this does not seem to affect the detection of the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED!

I finally found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184251

The problem was known and is fixed with a new kernel version.

I updated my system:

```
    # apt-get install linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic
    # apt-get install linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic
    # apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.11.0-14-generic
```

and everything seems ok now:

```
    $ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 004: ID 057c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:1021 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. U8520
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    $ adb devices
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    List of devices attached
    E9V9MC11A1703545        device
```